# How to obtain nugget parameter from fit.variogram in gstat?

Tags: r, kriging, variogram, gstat

I have the following code where I fit a variogram using gstat.

```
vA = variogram(dep_var~elevation=x+y, data, cressie=TRUE)
vmodel = vgm("Sph")
vB = fit.variogram(vA,vmodel)
```

How can I get the nugget parameter from the '`vB`' variable?

I am using vB$psill[1] as the nugget but it is large.

Comment: We need some more details - what value is it? why do you think its too large? what does the variogram plot look like?